# how to attach to screen sessions within a loop?

Tags: linux, bash, session, loops, gnu-screen

I use a bash script to spawn screen sessions in "detached" mode (using -d -m options)
and name them (through -S ) and then I attach to them to give some commands
(through -r ):

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m -S session_name_1
screen -d -m -S session_name_2
screen -d -m -S session_name_3
...
screen -r session_name_1
screen -r session_name_2
screen -r session_name_3
```

when I do the whole process in a loop fashion I cannot attach to a screen
(the file **session_names.txt** is a file whose each line contains a session name):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  echo $line
  screen -d -m -S $line
done < session_names.txt

while read line; do
  echo $line
  screen -r $line
done < session_names.txt
```

I can't attach to a screen and this error occurs:

> "Must be connected to a terminal."

How I can overcome this problem and why this problem occurs?

Comment: is there a reason you're not using the `.screenrc` to launch 1 copy of screen, with N terminals available, just by putting the names etc in that cfg file? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the whole loop the standard input comes from the txt file, so screen is not seeing the terminal.

This should do it, but note that 'line' really means 'word' here.

```
for line in `cat session_names.txt`; do
  echo $line
  screen -r $line
done
```

Comment: `for var in $(cat file)` is inefficient because it generates and keeps the whole list, and susceptible to word splitting as you mentioned. Better ways are described in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 (see the last section titled 'How to keep other commands from "eating" the input').